# SIGSEV fault in scipy's eigh

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, eigenvalue

I am having problems with a 'SIGSEGV' fault when diagonalising matrices with scipy's `linalg.eigh`.

The following code reproduces the problem after a few iterations of the `for` loop:

```
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import scipy.linalg as linalg

a = sparse.random(128, 128, 0.8)
b = sparse.random(128, 128, 0.8)*1j
a = a + b
a = a + a.H

for i in range(0, 100):
        E, R = linalg.eigh(a.todense())
```

After stepping and debugging, the faults seem to happen when scipy calls LAPACK, but I am unsure as to what I can do to stop this from happening.

I am running python 3.7, using scipy 1.2.1 under macOS Catalina.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to not all memory being freed that is used for `E` and `R` and new `E` and `R` arrays being created every iteration. Also inserting a `gc.collect()` at end of the loop doesn't fix this. Deleting `E` and `R` after the end of each iteration, or making sure to not creating new array copies for `E` and `R` in every iteration fixes the issue, as shown in the two code snippets:

```py
#manually delete E and R at the end of each iteration
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import scipy.linalg as linalg

a = sparse.random(128, 128, 0.8)
b = sparse.random(128, 128, 0.8)*1j
a = a + b
a = a + a.H

for i in range(0, 100):
        E, R = linalg.eigh(a.todense())
        del(E)
        del(R)
```

```py
#create E and R before the loop and store eigenpairs directly into these arrays
import scipy.sparse as sparse
import scipy.linalg as linalg
import numpy as np

a = sparse.random(128, 128, 0.8)
b = sparse.random(128, 128, 0.8)*1j
a = a + b
a = a + a.H

E = np.empty(128, np.float)
R = np.empty((128, 128), np.complex)

for i in range(0, 100):
        E[:], R[:][:] = linalg.eigh(a.todense())
```